# WP admin broken. Not saving catgories or adding categories to menu

Tags: categories, menus, admin, wp-admin

Wordpress Admin panel is not saving categories when creating new post or editing it.
Also same problem with adding categories or pages to menu. 
It just doesn't save changes when I press update.

Comment: are there any javascript errors of some sort when you check them on firebug?

Comment: please do a check also for XML errors , sometimes white spaces after the PHP closing tag( at the end of files), may cause this issue

Comment: There are some XML errors... But I can not find whitespaces :(